# Insert arrows into a table

Tags: tables, pdftex

[image]

Above is the table is drawn in Mircosoft Word. Can insert the arrows like inserted in word in the LaTeX platform?

I have to insert arrows into the table or curly braces also would be fine.  I tried but I have not been able to get it.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. You can start using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/ to create a minimal working example: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: Dear Sir, I am particularly interested in how to draw those type of colored arrows in table.  I have generated the table using latex.  But I don't know how to insert those arrow which relates the contents of above row to down row using the arrows.  Can you please help in this regard Sir

Comment: It is, in this website, to put a minimal working example starting from a `\documentclass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to create the arrows using [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor). My is a simple example that it can be improved:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt} % Default value: 6pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % Default value: 1
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 36; green, 87; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (158.5,127.65) .. controls (158.5,108.76) and (135.44,93.45) .. (107,93.45) -- (107,78) .. controls (135.44,78) and (158.5,93.31) .. (158.5,112.2) ;\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 36; green, 87; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (158.5,112.2) .. controls (158.5,126.22) and (145.79,138.28) .. (127.6,143.55) -- (127.6,138.4) -- (107,154.13) -- (127.6,164.15) -- (127.6,159) .. controls (145.79,153.73) and (158.5,141.67) .. (158.5,127.65)(158.5,112.2) -- (158.5,127.65) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
A little text into table.\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 It's nice and Mathcha looks really powerful. How long did it take you to make that arrow with Mathcha?

Comment: @AndréC  aahah. I like the true....one second... to make that arrow with Mathcha.

Comment: Wow, really wonderful thanks for the help, Sir.

Comment: Thanks for sharing about `Mathcha`, new update to me...`+1`

Comment: @ManuS It has been a glad to help you :-)-

Comment: @MadyYuvi I am happy when I can contribuite to help an user. I use Mathcha only for the newbies.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. Also learned about new editor Mathcha.  Thanks for the information, Sir

Comment: @ManuS You're welcome.